# Delphi Copyfile fail on long filename (over MAX_PATH)

Tags: delphi

i have a source file to copy in a target position:

```
aSource := 'C:\very_very_very_long_path\myfile.exe'; // over 260 chars
aTarget := 'C:\normal_path\myfile.exe';

if not(CopyFile(PChar(aSource), PChar(aTarget), false)) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
```

this code raise exception with code 3 - which means `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`.

the target and source paths exists and if i rename the source to a less long name, it works.

How can i copy a file with long path (over `MAX_PATH`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delphi should follow the [Window convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath) of allowing long file names when supplied with the prefix `\\?\`. For example, convert `"D:\very long path"` to `"\\?\D:\very long path"`.

This prefix is only applicable when using the Unicode version of the API, `CopyFileW` in this case. If you are using Delphi 2009 or later, then `CopyFile` maps to `CopyFileW`. If you use an earlier version then you will need to explicitly call `CopyFileW`, and make sure that the string that you pass is UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: On top of this, you must make sure that you are using the Unicode API. So in versions earlier than 2009 more work is need to call `CopyFileW`.

Comment: Good point, I'll add that in.

Comment: [Per MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath): "*Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, `MAX_PATH` limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior.*" `CopyFileW` is one of the functions.

Answer (score -3):

A String literal only can be 255 Chars long. You can do something like this:

```
aSource := 'Patht 255 Chars'+'Rest of the Path';
```

Comment: It's pretty clear that this isn't the problem at hand. After all, the literal used in the question isn't over 260 characters so clearly the value used has been trimmed.